# NestJs .env Reading Issue with ConfigService

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

I've been working with NestJs recently and encountered an issue while attempting to read environment data from the .env file. The problem arises when I use the ConfigService within the NestJs service and module – it functions correctly. However, `if I manually create an instance of ConfigService`, it fails to work (`got undefined`).

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```js
import KcAdminClient from '@keycloak/keycloak-admin-client';

import { Issuer } from 'openid-client';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

const config = new ConfigService();

export const kcAdminClient = new KcAdminClient({
  realmName: config.get('KC_REALM'),
  baseUrl: config.get('KC_BASE_URL'),
});
```

I've verified that the properties KC_REALM and KC_BASE_URL are present in the .env file.

Could someone provide assistance in resolving this issue?

Comment: Why are you trying to instantiate the `ConfigService` on your own instead of letting the `ConfigModule` handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ConfigService in a Nest module. It's being injected by the DI. If you want this setup to work, consider creating a Keycloak service that will have a config service injected into it. There is a nest keycloak module on npm, although I haven't used it.

Alternatively, you can access env variables directly via `process.env`.